# List of Standard Actions for Function Keys

Tags: .net, windows

I am trying to setup some shortcuts for my application.  Some of the shortcuts are supposed to use Function Keys.

One in particular that the users wanted to use was F4 for "Process Orders".  I found out (by accident) that F4 will cause a ComboBox to drop down.  (Leaving my command unfired.)

This leads me to ask, what do the other buttons do?

- **F1**: Help
- **F2**: Rename
- **F3**: ?
- **F4**: ComboBox Drop Down
- **F5**: ?
- **F6**: ?
- **F7**: ?
- **F8**: ?
- **F9**: ?
- **F10**: ?
- **F11**: ?
- **F12**: ?

**Is there standard functionality or commonly accepted uses for any other function keys?**

Comment: http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000306.htm Bam Google. Not sure how comprehensive that is but it should get you started.

Comment: @Pow-lan - I saw that list.  I find it hard to trust since it does not have the "F4=ComboBox Drop Down" item.

Comment: fair enough. I also stumbled upon this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/126449. It aslso lacks the F4 = combo box. What version of visual studio did you use? Maybe it is a winforms shortcut key issue. This post does not speak about why it happens bu at least it is mentioned: http://www.vbdotnetforums.com/vb-net-general-discussion/23903-combobox-f4-key.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be a great place to start cause it mentions F4 drop down combo:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms971323.aspx#atg_keyboardshortcuts_windows_shortcut_keys

Look specifically under the heading: `Dialog Box and Common Controls Shortcut Keys`

Comment: This one made it easiest to figure out what gets used for what.  I could search for "F4" and find what uses it.

Comment: I think I just advanced to fifth Dan in Google-Fu. Glad to help.

Answer (score 2):

The Windows 7 list of keyboard shortcuts [is here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/Windows7/Keyboard-shortcuts).  It is a long list, I'll annotate  the ones you asked for:

- F1: Help
- F2: Rename
- F3: Search
- F4: Display items in active list
- F5: Refresh
- F6: Select next
- F10: Activate menu
- F11: Maximize/restore window

Do note that most of these only need to implemented if the associated command is meaningful.  Only F10 is always implemented by default if the program has a menu.  Yes, ComboBox recognizes F4, not something I worry about too much when I have a better use for that key, the shortcut is obscure.  Your only choice is whether or not you let ComboBox use the key.  You hijack it before ComboBox sees it with, say, ProcessCmdKey().

And note how Visual Studio doesn't exactly observe this list either.

Comment: F6 is implemented by default for MDI windows.

Answer (score 0):

See this reference: http://www.guidingtech.com/10678/best-uses-of-function-keys-f1-f2-f12-windows/

Most important and common:

```
F1: Help
F2: Enable edit (e.g. file rename)
F3: Search
F4: 
F5: Refresh or Start
F6: Switch tabs/panes
F7:
F8:
F9
F10: Menu access
F11: Full screen mode
F12: Save As
```